# Adding/removing Owner in MultiSigWallet

Tags: solidity, wallets, multisignature

I'm trying to understand the logic of Consensys' MultiSigWallet and being stuck with the understanding that onlyWallet can call addOwner() or removeOwner() or replaceOwner().

There are no such function-calls in the contract. It looks like it is for externals (human) calls.

On the other hand, the onlyWallet() modifier that will "revert() if the caller != contract itself" and prevent such calls.

How does it work? 
Who can actually call these functions and how exactly?

Comment: Can you add smart contract code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, I just found that transactions can send the code as a "byte data" param and thus call any contract's functions.  :)

> addTransaction(address destination, uint value, **bytes data**)